# Table heading not getting downloading in csv format using jQuery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have to do export table datas from CSV Format,if i am clicking the Export Table data into Excel link means i have to download table datas,with heading names.but for me heading name not getting downloading only table datas is downloading , if any one know means please update my snippet. i tried from morning onwards but  i couldn't solve this propeblem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

          function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

          var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

      // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
      // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
      tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
      tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

      // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
      colDelim = '","',
      rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

      // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
      csv = '"' + $rows.map(function(i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
          $cols = $row.find('td');

        return $cols.map(function(j, col) {
          var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.text();

          return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

      }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
      .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
      .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

    // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

      var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
      });

      // Crashes in IE 10, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge
      // See MS Edge Issue #10396033
      // Hence, the deliberate 'false'
      // This is here just for completeness
      // Remove the 'false' at your own risk
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
      // HTML5 Blob        
      var blob = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
      });
      var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvUrl
        });
    } else {
      // Data URI
      var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvData,
          'target': '_blank'
        });
    }
  }

  // This must be a hyperlink
  $(".export").on('click', function(event) {
    // CSV
    var args = [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv'];

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

    // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
             <a href="#" class="export">Export Table data into Excel</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body dvData" id="dvData">
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Rendering engine</th>
                  <th>Browser</th>
                  <th>Platform(s)</th>
                  <th>Engine version</th>
                  <th>CSS grade</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 4.0
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 95+</td>
                  <td> 4</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.0
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 95+</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.5
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 95+</td>
                  <td>5.5</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 6
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 98+</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                  <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it,, the things that we changed are in the beginning of the function to reference every `tr` element

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr')
```

and also inside loop to catch any `td` or `th` element

```
$row.find('td,th');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr'),

      // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
      // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
      tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
      tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

      // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
      colDelim = '","',
      rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

      // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
      csv = '"' + $rows.map(function(i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
          $cols = $row.find('td,th');

        return $cols.map(function(j, col) {
          var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.text();

          return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

      }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
      .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
      .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

    // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

      var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
      });

      // Crashes in IE 10, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge
      // See MS Edge Issue #10396033
      // Hence, the deliberate 'false'
      // This is here just for completeness
      // Remove the 'false' at your own risk
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
      // HTML5 Blob        
      var blob = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
      });
      var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvUrl
        });
    } else {
      // Data URI
      var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvData,
          'target': '_blank'
        });
    }
  }

  // This must be a hyperlink
  $(".export").on('click', function(event) {
    // CSV
    var args = [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv'];

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

    // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <a href="#" class="export">Export Table data into Excel</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body dvData" id="dvData">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 4.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td> 4</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.5
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5.5</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 6
          </td>
          <td>Win 98+</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
          <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>

        </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are exporting data only from `td` elements. But your header data is in `th` elements.